# Retina logo scaled in iPhone 5 portrait mode?

Tags: iphone, retina-display

My retina logo doesn't work on the iPhone 5 in portrait mode: it's a bit blurry. In landscape it works fine, maybe it's scaled in portrait mode?

This is the URL: stefaanoyen.be

This is my CSS:

```
.title-area {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 35%;
    height: 140px;
    background: url(images/logo.png) no-repeat center left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

@media (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
       (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       (min-resolution: 144dpi),
       (min-resolution: 1.5dppx) {
    .title-area {   
        background: url(images/logo@2x.png)  no-repeat center left;
        background-size: 391px 75px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a relative width `width: 35%;`, which means it will change if its parent's width is not a fixed value.